# JQuery $.ajax success data is always empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, rest

I am using JQuery's $.ajax to call a REST method and wanted to update the HTML div with the return data.
However, the success data is always empty though the webserver indicates a 200 response.
The expected response is just plain text.
Also, when I call the REST method via browser, the expected response is displayed.

here are the contents of my JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() {
    var result = "none";
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://<local_server:port>/<string_parameter>/',
        type: 'GET', 
        aysnc: false,
        success: function(data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });
    document.getElementById("texthere").innerHTML = result;
}
}
```

contents of the "result" var remains "none".
Here's my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="texthere"Going to be updated when button is clicked</div><br />
    <div style="width:200px">
        <button id="button">Update</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've seen related questions and their recommendations of setting async to false and cross-domain to false did not work. What am I missing here? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

**EDITED**
I tried to debug it using Google Chrome's Java Script Console and I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://<server:port>/<param>/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Should I do something on the server or I can do a workaround on my client side script?
Thanks again

**UPDATED**
I tried it using IE11 and the data is now displayed on the HTML divs.
However, I want to run it on different browsers. What should I do then on the client side script or on the server side?

**UPDATED**
I was able to make it work properly by allowing CORS on the server side. I am using Django for my server side script so I need to tweak some entries on my settings.py and add an additional class. In case some is using Django and having the same issue as mine, [this guide will help you allow CORS.](https://gist.github.com/strogonoff/1369619)

Comment: there is a typo with `aysnc`, should be `async`

Comment: Your HTML is not well formed. Close the div tag for the div with the id "texthere"

Comment: not the case..just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many misconceptions.

- Use **`async`** instead of `aysnc` (only if you really needed)
- `cross-domain` is only needed if the call is made to different domain (don't look that's  your case)
- `result` value is not accesible outside the ajax function, try: `result = dataFunction(data);` to export the `data` to a external function or just change the content inside the ajax function.
- Personal opinion, use `.ready()` instead of `.load()`
- If you are using `jQuery` why not used allways?

**MAIN REASON:** *Malformed `HTML` & `JS` example code in OP.*

> ### EDITED
>
> *tested and working...* see: <kbd>[JsFiddel example](http://jsfiddle.net/YVyV5/)</kbd>

#### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="texthere">Going to be updated when button is clicked</div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <button id="button">Update</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### my.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'your.file',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#texthere').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Further reader: [jquery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Try with POST instead of GET in Ajax Type.

Comment: BTW, are you getting the error alert or still the empty response? Any errors in the console?

Comment: thanks for the consistent help @gmo. But i think this is not the case. I am updating my question because I discovered a new error when I debug it using Google Chrome's java script console. Kindly check my edited question and hopefully, can provide feedback again.Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I can't without more information. How you handled `<server:port>` & `<param>` vars? Are you running your file from another domain (It's look like now).. Can you duplicate your code in a `jsFiddle`?

Comment: I was able to make it work by allowing CORS on the server side. But still, I will be tagging this as the answer for my question since this led me to find the root cause. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Was rough to find, but you did it.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because of the typo aysnc instead of async. That said, I would recommend to avoid synchronous ajax calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("texthere").innerHTML = result;
```

Put that statement within your success or create a promise. Javascript does not behave like server side code while your ajax call is made the execution of the script side code will continue on - so initially the value of result is nothing and even thought your webservice call comes back with a success there is no way to go back and update the value without either adding the update to the element inside the success handler or using a promise.

Just as an addon - it seems that your HTML is not well formed either -

```
<div id="texthere"Going to be updated when button is clicked</div>
```

should be

```
<div id="texthere">Going to be updated when button is clicked</div>
```

Comment: thank you. tried putting it inside the success bracket but still, data is empty. How do I create a promise?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){document.getElementById("button").onclick = function()
{     
$.ajax({url: 'http://<local_server:port>/<string_parameter>/',
        type: 'GET',success: function(data){document.getElementById("textwhere").innerHTML = data;}});}
}
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to put some explanation along with your code.